# MediaPipe Hand Tracking for Video

Tags: python, opencv, mediapipe

https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/docs/solutions/hands.md It says under ML pipeline that MediaPipe can generate cropped hand images based on the previous frame so that palm detection does not need to be invoked every time. I am implementing MediaPipe hand tracking in python to analyze a video. Is there a way to determine whether palm detection is being implemented on every frame of the video or not?

My code is something along the lines of

```
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(mp4)
    while cap.isOpened():
        sucess, img = cap.read()
        results = mp.solutions.hands.Hand.process(img)
```